# Insert comma after last character in a SQL string

Tags: mysql, sql, string, phpmyadmin

I have a table like this:

```
id | name
+++++++++
1 | ab
2 | bq
3 | g
4 | qaa
5 | e
```

I'd like to add a comma "," after the last character for each row in a column.
So I need it to be:

```
id | name
+++++++++
1 | ab,
2 | bq,
3 | g,
4 | qaa,
5 | e,
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know why are you  doing this but i guess its bad idea.

you can add the comma when you fetch the values and your values stays clean in database for future use.

example

```
  echo $row['name']."," ;
```

AND also you dont have to insert them with comma,you just make it difficul for you while its easy to add it when you fetch it.

**EDIT:**

if you wanna update table with comma then use `CONCAT` like this:

```
  update yourtable set name =concat(name, ',')
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but i have a reason to do this.

Comment: can you tell what reason ? so i can help you ?

Answer (score 2):

```
update table set name=name+','
```